# Hide <Run /> tag in TextBlock - WPF

Tags: wpf

I have textblock with 2 `Run` tags and one `Linebreak`:

```
  <TextBlock>
      <Run Text="TopText"/>
      <LineBreak/>
      <Run x:Name="bottomRun" Text="Bottom text"/>
  </TextBlock>
```

I want to hide second `Run` tag in code behind. But there is no `Visible` property... Why is it so?
What is the best solution how to hide only one `Run` tag?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Visibility` is the property in the `UIElement` class which all UI controls derive from but `Run` doesn't derive from it.

Best you can do is to set `Text` property to `String.Empty` in code behind:

```
bottomRun.Text = String.Empty;
```

Comment: @tofutim It does work from Style. But you cannot overwrite in Style things that were set directly in the object; you need to set the value *only* in the style, and then overwrite it in a trigger inside the style.

Comment: @ANeves - Are you sure? because as stated `Run` doesn't have any property `Visibility` associated with it, then how it can be set from Style?

Comment: RohitVas, I wrote nothing about Visibility. Did you misunderstand? If not, can you please rewrite your comment?

Answer (score 10):

The TextBlock you've got is pretty small.  When faced with a similar situation, I duplicated it and bound the Visiblity property on TextBlock.

```
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding Path=LicenseValid, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=false }">
      <Run Text="TopText"/>
      <LineBreak/>
      <Run x:Name="bottomRun" Text="Bottom text"/>
  </TextBlock>

<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding Path=LicenseValid, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=false }">
      <Run Text="TopText"/>
      <LineBreak/>
      <Run x:Name="bottomRun" Text="Bottom text"/>
  </TextBlock>
```

The converter is suitably declared, defined and takes an 'invert' parameter.

Answer (score 6):

You can user Style Trigger with Binding :

```
<Run>
    <Run.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Run">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="Bottom text"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=variable}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value=""/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Run.Style>
</Run>
```

Comment: This is a solution I think that's in the spirit of the original question and is a good answer, I just hate how verbose XAML is sometimes!

Answer (score 2):

I know the OP wanted to solve this using a single TextBlock with Runs in it, but I solved the problem with a Horizontally oriented StackPanel of TextBlocks.  It's a heavier solution since there are more controls involved, but works.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this is appropriate - but not ideal if you truly need the text to 'run' and you want to have an automatic linebreak in the inline element.

```
<TextBlock>
    <InlineUIElement><TextBlock Visibility="Collapsed" Text="TopText"/></InlineUIElement>
    <LineBreak/>
    <Run x:Name="bottomRun" Text="Bottom text"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `<InlineUIElement/>` must be child of `<InlineUIContainer/>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
bottomRun.Text = "";
```

This one works for me.